# How to save data in my database with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

When I send data to my php file. Data is not getting stored in the database. My php code is below.

I am using one.com as my host. There I can use to php code using some components. So  I gave an external link to the button to submit to php file.
But I cannot submit data to php code using button name or class attribute.
How can I store data in database using php file.

Please help me in this issue.Thank you in advance.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="register.php">
   <div class="input-group">
     <lable>Username</lable>
     <input type="text" name="Username" required>
   </div>
   <div class="input-group">
      <lable>Email</lable>
      <input type="text" name="Email" required>
   </div>
   <div class="input-group">
      <lable>Password</lable>
      <input type="password" name="password_1" required></div>

   <div class="input-group">
      <lable>Confirm Password</lable>
      <input type="password" name="password_2" required>
   </div>
   <p>Already a User?</p>
  </form>
```

PHP:

```
    <?php
    $Username = "";
    $Email = "";
    $errors = array();

    // connect to the database

    $db = mysqli_connect('hostname', 'root', 'password', 'dbname');
    echo "database connected";

    // if the register button is clicked

    $username = $_POST['Username'];
    $email = $_POST['Email'];
    $password_1 = $_POST['password_1'];
    $password_2 = $_POST['password_2'];
    echo "data is taken";

    // if there are no errors, save user to database

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Users(Username, Email, password) VALUES('$username', 
 '$email', '$password_1')";
    mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    echo "data inserted successfully";
    ?>
```

Comment: except if i didn't well understand the problem here is that you have to use a form to send your data in the php file, not simply a link on a button.

Comment: can you also post the code from the Form you are passing it from

Comment: Post your HTML form code so we can help you.

Comment: Also your MySQL code is faulty it's wide open to a MySQL injection attack don't use variables directly inside the SQL statement use prepared statements with your mysqli.

Comment: Ya sure actually I am developing website in one.com which provides platform to publish the website.

Comment: So in that site there is no facility to give button as if we give button we couldn't link to php file.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the code except for that you're open to a SQL injection which your really need to fix and learn PDO or mysqli. It seems to be a problem with your hosting service your better switch and get another better hosting company for your site which provides real hosting.

Comment: What happens when you run this script?  What is the output?  Are there errors in your logs?  You don't check that you got the parameters you need, that you connected to the database and got a mysqli handle, or the result of your query.  As pointed out, you use the wrong technique for this query, when you should be using bind variables.  I'm amused by the fact that unless your database prevents this with a unique index, you could have 10 users with the same username.  A person could make 100 accounts with the same email. If you do have a unique index on these things, your code doesn't catch it

Comment: I am not getting any errors but when I give static data it is storing in database. But when I want send dynamic data it is not storing.

Comment: I think dynamic data is not entering into $ name = $_post[name];

Comment: Here I am using unique index as ID which is auto increment in db

Answer (score 1):

Is your database correct?

```
// connect to the database

$db = mysqli_connect('hostname', 'root', 'password', 'dbname');
echo "database connected";
```

And remember it always printed "database connected".